# Problem in installing g++

Tags: package-management, g++

**I want to install g++ on my laptop(ubutu 14.04 LTS), however it shows the following errors-**

> maddman@MADDY-PC:~/Desktop$ *sudo apt-get install g++*
>
> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>
> The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> *g++ : Depends: g++-4.8 (>= 4.8.2-5~) but it is not going to be installed*
>
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
>
> Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

**Also every time i run update, it shows following error**

> W: Failed to fetch 
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/picaso/octave/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/picaso/octave/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Some search, i found a relevant answer here... [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

> However, for me the following command worked out

**sudo apt-get install ppa-purge**

and then i ran the command for installing g++ and it installed successfully.